# PyTorch: Index high dimensional tensor with two dimensional tensor

Tags: numpy, indexing, pytorch

Suppose I have the following tensors:

```
N = 2
k = 3
d = 2

L = torch.arange(N * k * d * d).view(N, k, d, d)
L
tensor([[[[ 0,  1],
          [ 2,  3]],

         [[ 4,  5],
          [ 6,  7]],

         [[ 8,  9],
          [10, 11]]],


        [[[12, 13],
          [14, 15]],

         [[16, 17],
          [18, 19]],

         [[20, 21],
          [22, 23]]]])


index = torch.Tensor([0,1,0,0]).view(N,-1)
index
tensor([[0., 1.],
        [0., 0.]])
```

I now would like to use the index tensor to pick out the corresponding matrices on the second dimension, i.e. I would like to get something like:

```
tensor([[[[ 0,  1],
          [ 2,  3]],

         [[ 4,  5],
          [ 6,  7]]],


        [[[12, 13],
          [14, 15]],

         [[[[12, 13],
          [14, 15]]])
```

Any idea how I could achieve this?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensors can be indexed with multiple tensors specified across different dimensions (tuples of tensors), where the *i-th* element of each tensor are combined to create a tuple of indices, i.e. `data[indices_dim0, indices_dim1]` results in indexing `data[indices_dim0[0], indices_dim1[0]]`, `data[indices_dim0[1], indices_dim1[1]]` and so on. They must have the same length `len(indices_dim0) == len(indices_dim1)`.

Let's use the flat version of `index` (before you applied the view). Each element needs to be matched to the appropriate batch index, which would be `[0, 0, 1, 1]`. Also `index` needs to have type `torch.long`, because floats cannot be used as indices. [`torch.tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor) should be preferred for creating tensors with existing data, since `torch.Tensor` is an alias for the default tensor type (`torch.FloatTensor`), whereas `torch.tensor` automatically uses the data type that represents the given values, but also supports the `dtype` argument to set the type manually, and is generally more versatile.

```py
# Type torch.long is inferred
index = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 0])

# Same, but explicitly setting the type
index = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=torch.long)

batch_index = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 1])

L[batch_index, index]
# => tensor([[[ 0,  1],
#             [ 2,  3]],
#
#            [[ 4,  5],
#             [ 6,  7]],
#
#            [[12, 13],
#             [14, 15]],
#
#            [[12, 13],
#             [14, 15]]])
```

The indices are not limited to 1D tensors, but they all need to have the same size and each element is used as one index, for example with 2D tensors the indexing happens as `data[indices_dim0[i][j], indices_dim1[i][j]]`
With 2D tensors it happens to be much simpler to create the batch indices without having to do it manually.

```py
index = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 0]).view(N, -1)
# => tensor([[0, 1],
#            [0, 0]])

# Every batch gets its index and is repeated across dim=1
batch_index = torch.arange(N).view(N, 1).expand_as(index)
# => tensor([[0, 0],
#            [1, 1]])

L[batch_index, index]
```